# Python can't implement timeit module

Tags: python, timing

This is a basic exercise. I just don't know hot to implement the timeit module correctly. I keep recieving syntax errors

```
import timeit
import random
def bubblesort(LAux):
    for i in range(len(LAux)): 
    exchange = False 
    for j in range(len(LAux)-1): 
        if LAux[j] > LAux[j+1]: 
            tmp = LAux[j+1] 
            LAux[j+1] = LAux[j] 
            LAux[j] = tmp 
            exchange = True
    if not exchange: 
        break
return(LAux)

a=int(input("Size of list: "))
lst = [0]*a
for i in range(a):
    lst[i] = random.randint(1,100)
print(bubblesort(lst))
print(timeit.timeit()
```

Comment: please provide the syntax errors.

Comment: Lines 5, 12, 13, 14 needs to be indented and you're missing a closing parentheses on the last line; pretty much what the error message tells you.

Comment: For me it works if you put a `)` behind the last `print()`

Comment: Please provide syntax error. As i have noticed. Error is "print(timeit.timeit()". You missed second parenthesis ")".

Comment: That code isn't indented properly, and it's missing a closing parenthesis `)` at the end. What do you expect `print(timeit.timeit())` to do? You haven't given it anything to perform a timing test on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Actually i want to calculate the execution time of the bubblesort function. I didn't notice that missing parenthesis and I just realized that, somehow, it works if i run the code with it. But according to the python documentation, the module needs 4 arguments. So, any ideas how to use it? or maybe the number it shows me its the time i'm looking for.

Comment: BTW, there's a better way to swap things in Python. You don't need that `tmp`, you can just do `LAux[j], LAux[j+1] =  LAux[j+1], LAux[j]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misinterpreted the function of [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#examples) - the idea is that you tell it what to actually time, and it then times it. Normally, it does the thing you're timing many, many times, so you can get a meaningful average. This means it also needs to provide a 'setup' argument, as the list should presumably be different for each test. Refer to the examples in the documentation if you need - I normally find that they're easy enough to suit to your purpose. I've implemented timeit below:

```
a=int(input("Size of list: "))

n = 100000

setup = "lst = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(a)]"
time = timeit.timeit("bubblesort(lst)", setup=setup, globals=globals(), number=n)

print("{} sorts took {}s".format(n, time))
```

Of course, if you're using IPython you can do something like this:

```
In [1]: from bubble import bubblesort

In [2]: from random import randrange

In [3]: %timeit bubblesort([randrange(100) for _ in range(50)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 175 µs per loop
```

Maybe you were expecting timeit() to tell you just how much time has passed. If so, this could be done using the `time` module, quite simply.

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
bubblesort(lst)
time_taken = time.time() - start_time
print("One sort took {}s".format(time_taken))
```

On another note, I'd recommend using a different name for the argument "Laux". As you can see, SO's syntax highlighting thinks it's a class, as normally anything starting with a capital letter is a class. Laux also doesn't particularly tell me as an outsider what it is, although I can infer from the name bubblesort.